# How to send nested multi part form data in android using retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, multipartform-data, okhttp

i have to send a response to my api, which expects the response in the format below:

```
 "group":{
     "group_name": "father group",
     "group_category": "family"
 },
 "member":[
     {
         "full_name": "Hassan",
         "profile_pic":"hello",
     "dob": "12-08-1992"}
 ],
 "representative":{
     "first_name": "Jabir",
     "last_name": "Addaib",
     "campaign":438,
     "phone":"08011840622",
     "password":"simon123",
     "username":"simon",
      "profile_pic":"hello",
     "gender":"male",
     "dob":"2002-12-08",
     "email":"tule34@gmail.com"
 }

}
```

as you can use i have a profile pic file being sent in an array list of members and as well as a profile pic in the representative body, dont mind the dummy string "hello",

so my question is how do i send this data in a way that the images are also uploaded,
so far what i have tried include

**RETROFIT INTERFACE FUNCTION**

```
 suspend fun onboardGroupBeneficiary(
        @Part("group") group: GroupBeneficiaryGroupDetails,
        @Part members: List<MultipartBody.Part>,
        @Part representative: MultipartBody.Part,
        @Header("Authorization") authorization: String,
    ): OnboardGroupBeneficiaryResponse
```

**MY REPOSITORY FUNCTION SENDING TO RETROFIT INTERFACE**,
I have already created a data class for the response which is being used by this function to create a multipart form

```
 val memberParts = mutableListOf<MultipartBody.Part>()

            for (member in body.member) {

                val memberImageFileCompressed = File(member.profile_pic)
                val memberProfilePicBody = compressed.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())

                val imagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                    "profile_pic",
                    memberImageFileCompressed.absolutePath.substringAfterLast("/"),
                    memberProfilePicBody,
                )

                val memberPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                    "member",
                    null,
                    MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("full_name", member.full_name)
                        .addFormDataPart("dob", member.dob)
                        .addFormDataPart("profile_pic", member.profile_pic)
                     //   .addPart(imagePart)
                        .build(),
                )

                memberParts.add(memberPart)
            }

            val representativePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                "representative",
                null,
                MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("first_name",firstName )
                    .addFormDataPart("last_name", lastName)
                    .addFormDataPart("email", email)
                    .addFormDataPart("phone", phone)
                    .addFormDataPart("password", password)
                    .addFormDataPart("latitude", latitude.toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("longitude", longitude.toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("iris", iris.toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("location", location)
                    .addFormDataPart("location", location)
                    .addFormDataPart("nin", nin)
                    .addFormDataPart("gender", gender)
                    .addFormDataPart("dob", this.date)
                    .addFormDataPart("campaign", campaignId)
                    .addFormDataPart("profile_pic", profilePic.toString())
               //     .addPart(image)
                    .build(),
            )


              val response=  api.onboardGroupBeneficiary(
                    body.group,
                    memberParts,
                        representativePart,
                    authorization = ngoToken,
                )
```

but this gives me an error saying
`representative firstname field is required` meaning it isn't sending the form properly